# Unable to request different custom URL for Google+

Tags: google-plus, google-plus-pages

I received the notification on Google+ Page pre-approved custom URL and would like to request a different URL. On the Google+ Help Page it stated that we can request a different URL but there was no such option for our page. Looking around the internet, I could not find anyone with a similar situation and tried accessing the page as manager.

[image]

From my research, other people do have the option to request different suitable URL for their page.

Answer (score 4):

There has been a lot of discussion about this in the [Google+ Help Community](https://plus.google.com/communities/115758385206378551362)

There is no option for requesting a different custom url at this time. If you are unhappy with this process, please send Feedback (in the left-hand drop down menu). The team looks at each and every piece of feedback sent in, and the more feedback they get on a particular topic, the more this becomes a priority.